# pgbench install?

Tags: mac-osx, postgresql

I'm running postgres 8.4 but pgbench does not appear to be installed on my Mac.  I've looked but I am unable to find anywhere where I can get a copy of pgbench to augment my postgres install.  Looking at documentation I thought pgbench ws included in postgres 8.3 and higher, but I could be wrong.

Does anyone know where I can download and install a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgbench is part of what PostgreSQL calls its contrib extensions.  They are all included with the PostgreSQL source, but sometimes packagers break them into a separate installation package.  I know with Macports getting the contrib modules installed is really painful.  If you used something like EnterpriseDB's one-click installer instead, whether to install them or not was probably an option you had.  Without knowing which package and version you installed, it's hard to say how to get them; having the right things to search for might help you out though.